# Vue - how to pass down slots inside wrapper component?

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-component, wrapper, bootstrap-vue

So I've created a simple wrapper component with template like:

```
<wrapper>
   <b-table v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners"></b-table>
</wrapper>
```

using `$attrs` and `$listeners` to pass down props and events.
Works fine, but how can the wrapper proxy the `<b-table>` named slots to the child?

Comment: FYI, this is going to be solved in [this new PR](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/7765).

But if you want to have a solution right now, this [github comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/7765#issuecomment-396822866) would help. 

tested: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/bptLavov/185/

Answer (score 195, accepted):

**Vue 3**

Same as the Vue 2.6 example below except:

- `$listeners` has been merged into `$attrs` so `v-on="$listeners"` is no longer necessary. See the [migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/listeners-removed.html).
- `$scopedSlots` is now just `$slots`. See [migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/slots-unification.html).

```vue
<template v-for="(_, slot) of $slots" v-slot:[slot]="scope || {}"><slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope"/></template>
```

---

**Vue 2.6 (v-slot syntax)**

All ordinary slots will be added to scoped slots, so you only need to do this:

```vue
<wrapper>
  <b-table v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
    <template v-for="(_, slot) of $scopedSlots" v-slot:[slot]="scope"><slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope"/></template>
  </b-table>
</wrapper>
```

---

**Vue 2.5**

See [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52823029/734040).

---

**Original answer**

You need to specify the slots like this:

```vue
<wrapper>
  <b-table v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
    <!-- Pass on the default slot -->
    <slot/>

    <!-- Pass on any named slots -->
    <slot name="foo" slot="foo"/>
    <slot name="bar" slot="bar"/>

    <!-- Pass on any scoped slots -->
    <template slot="baz" slot-scope="scope"><slot name="baz" v-bind="scope"/></template>
  </b-table>
</wrapper>
```

---

**Render function**

```js
render(h) {
  const children = Object.keys(this.$slots).map(slot => h('template', { slot }, this.$slots[slot]))
  return h('wrapper', [
    h('b-table', {
      attrs: this.$attrs,
      on: this.$listeners,
      scopedSlots: this.$scopedSlots,
    }, children)
  ])
}
```

You probably also want to set [`inheritAttrs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs) to false on the component.

Comment: The answer for "Vue 2.6" doesn't work for me when using a named slot (on vue 2.6.11). If I remove the parts `="scope"` and `v-bind="scope"`, it works for named slots but I can't use it for scoped slots any more :(

Comment: I'm having the same issue with 2.6. It seems that the issue is with trying to access the scope o non-scoped slots. Sergey's answer below has worked for me.

Answer (score 92):

I have been automating the passing of any (and all) slots using `v-for`, as shown  below. The nice thing with this method is that you don't need to know which slots have to be passed on, including the default slot. Any slots passed to the wrapper will be passed on.

```html
<wrapper>
  <b-table v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">

    <!-- Pass on all named slots -->
    <slot v-for="slot in Object.keys($slots)" :name="slot" :slot="slot"/>

    <!-- Pass on all scoped slots -->
    <template v-for="slot in Object.keys($scopedSlots)" :slot="slot" slot-scope="scope"><slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope"/></template>

  </b-table>
</wrapper>
```

Comment: This line is the magic if you wanna use the scoped slots from parent for vuetify data-tables (you wanna specify the UI for a specific column from parent component wrapping the data-table). 

`<template v-for="slot in Object.keys($scopedSlots)" :slot="slot" slot-scope="scope"><slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope"/></template>`

Answer (score 14):

Here is updated syntax for vue **>2.6** with scoped slots and regular slots, thanks Nikita-Polyakov, [link to discussion](https://gist.github.com/loilo/73c55ed04917ecf5d682ec70a2a1b8e2)

```js
<!-- pass through scoped slots -->
<template v-for="(_, scopedSlotName) in $scopedSlots" v-slot:[scopedSlotName]="slotData">
  <slot :name="scopedSlotName" v-bind="slotData" />
</template>

<!-- pass through normal slots -->
<template v-for="(_, slotName) in $slots" v-slot:[slotName]>
  <slot :name="slotName" />
</template>

<!-- after iterating over slots and scopedSlots, you can customize them like this -->
<template v-slot:overrideExample>
    <slot name="overrideExample" />
    <span>This text content goes to overrideExample slot</span>
</template>
```

Answer (score 12):

This solution for Vue 3.2 version and above

```
<template v-for="(_, slot) in $slots" v-slot:[slot]="scope">
    <slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope || {}" />
</template>
```

Comment: This works great except when the slot is dynamically created and rendered as a fragment or text root node... then you get a ton of `Vue Warn`s in the dev console.  I ran into this issue when wanting to wrap the Kendo UI Grid component and exposing its cell template slots.

Comment: What does make it specific to 3.2?

Comment: I'm getting a typescript error at `[slot]`: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be used to index type {...}`. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Same here.  It does seem to run correctly, as far as I can tell, but VSCode flags it as a type error.  If I use this method, ALL of my wrapper components will be flagged in the Explorer as files with errors, potentially hiding real errors down the line...

Comment: I figured out how to fix the typescript error (by accident): You need to`import` the component you are wrapping, even if it's already globally registered. (e.g. wrapping Quasar's QInput component, you need to add `import { QInput } from 'quasar'` to your component.)

Answer (score 0):

For Vue 3 with Typescript, using Vuetify as an example.

```js
<template>
  <v-autocomplete
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-on="$listeners"
  >
    <template
      v-for="slotName in slotsNamesToPassThrough"
      #[slotName]="slotProps"
    >
      <slot
        v-if="slotName === 'prepend-item'"
        :name="slotName"
        v-bind="slotProps"
      >
        <v-list-item><em>Search for a user ...</em></v-list-item>
      </slot>
      <slot
        v-else
        :name="slotName"
        v-bind="slotProps"
      ></slot>
    </template>
  </v-autocomplete>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { computed, useSlots } from "vue"

import type { VAutocomplete } from "vuetify/lib/components/index.mjs"

type WrappedSlotNames = keyof VAutocomplete["$slots"]
const wrappedSlotNames = new Set<WrappedSlotNames>([
  "append-inner",
  "append-item",
  "append",
  "chip",
  "clear",
  "details",
  "item",
  "label",
  "loader",
  "message",
  "no-data",
  "prepend-inner",
  "prepend-item",
  "prepend",
  "selection",
])

const slots = useSlots()

const slotsNamesToPassThrough = computed(() => {
  return Object.keys(slots).filter((slotName): slotName is WrappedSlotNames =>
    wrappedSlotNames.has(slotName as WrappedSlotNames)
  )
})
</script>
```

The key parts are:

1. Re-defining a list of slot names that the original component provides. I hate this part, as I feel like it breaks the key value of inheritance and slot pass-through in general. I haven't found a workaround.
2. Filtering the computed result of `useSlots()` to build a list of slots that have been passed to the component, filtered by the list of slots that are allowed by the wrapped component.
3. Providing new defaults for slots via `v-if="slotName === 'some-name'"`

Positives:

1. If you provide an invalid slot name you will get a type error.

Negatives:

1. If you miss providing a valid slot name, you will not get a type error.

Is this nice? No. Does it work and solve some basic type safety things? Yes. Hopefully there will be some future improvements to TypeScript or Vue or Vuetify that make inheritance easier and slot pass-through easier.