# Vuejs nested slots: how to pass slot to grandchild

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I use different vuetify components, for example [v-menu](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus). It has a template like this:

```
<v-menu>
  <a slot="activator">menu</a>
  <v-list>
    <v-list-tile>Menu Entry 1</v-list-tile>
    <v-list-tile>Menu Entry 2</v-list-tile>
  </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

Suppose I want to add another wrapper around it. That is my special menu component that has some predefined menu options. And I want it to has an activator slot as well. And the last should be somehow assigned to the original v-menu activator slot. Is it possible?

Example:

```
// index.vue: 
<template>
  <my-special-menu>
    <button>My special menu trigger</button>
  </my-special-menu>
</template>

// MySpecialMenu.vue
<template>
  <v-menu>
    <slot slot="activator"/> <-- I don't know how to write this line
    <v-list>...</v-list>
  </v-menu>
</template>
```

`<slot slot="activator">` is an incorrect equation. The goal is to pull the content from the parent (that is `<button>..</button>` in the example), and use it as `slot="activator"` in v-menu.

I can write it like this:

```
<v-menu>
  <a slot="activator"><slot/></a>
  ...
</v-menu>
```

But this case the result template will be:

```
<div class="v-menu__activator">
  <a>
    <button>My special menu trigger</button>
  </a>
</div>
```

That's not exactly what I want. Is it possible to get rid off `<a>` wrapper here?

Update:
We can use a construction like `<template slot="activator"><slot name="activator"/></template>` to throw some slot to a grand child. But what if we have multiple slots and we want to proxy them all? That's like inheritAttrs and `v-bind="$attrs"` for slots. Is it currently possible?

For example, there's `<v-autocomplete>` component in vuetify that has append, prepend, label, no-data, progress, item, selection etc slots. I write some wrapper component around this, it currently looks like:

```
<template>
  <v-autocomplete ..>
    <template slot="append"><slot name="append"/></template>
    <template slot="prepend"><slot name="prepend"/></template>
    <template slot="label"><slot name="label"/></template>
    ...
    <template slot="item" slot-scope="props"><slot name="item" v-bind="props"/></template>
  </v-autocomplete>
</template>
```

Is it possible to avoid all slots enumeration here?

Comment: attribute `name` instead of `slot` so: `<slot name="activator">`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you put the `slot` attribute on a html element, that html element is passed to the child component to fill the slot with that name. If you don't want to pass along a html element, you can use `slot` on a `template` tag within your component. A template tag groups elements, but does not render to a html element, which is perfect here. You can use template tags also for other things, such as to group elements in a v-if for example, or to repeat multiple elements with a v-for.

```
// App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <test>
      <template slot="activator">
        Click <b>me</b>!
      </template>
    </test>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
// Test.vue
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <grand-child>
      <template slot="activator">
        <slot name="activator"></slot>
      </template>
    </grand-child>

    This is some text
  </div>
</template>
```

```
// GrandChild.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <a href="#" @click="toggle = !toggle">
      <slot name="activator">Default</slot>
    </a>

    <div v-if="toggle">This appears and disappears</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Edit: If you want to do this for arbitrary slots, this is also possible. `this.$slots` contains the slots and their content, so with something like the following, you can pass the slot content to a slot with the same name:

```
<grand-child>
  <template v-for="(_, slot) in $slots">
    <template :slot="slot">
      <slot :name="slot"></slot>
    </template>
  </template>
</grand-child>
```

[image: Edit Vue Template]

For completeness sake, scoped slots can be accessed through `$scopedSlots` and be propagated like so:

```
<grand-child>
  <template v-for="(_, slot) in $scopedSlots" v-slot:[slot]="props">
    <slot :name="slot" v-bind="props" />
  </template>
</grand-child>
```

<sup>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891858/vue-how-to-pass-down-slots-inside-wrapper-component) and [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430731/vuejs-nested-slots-how-to-pass-slot-to-grandchild/53431262?noredirect=1#comment113005031_53431262)</sup>

Comment: How do we then pass data?

Comment: Sorry, this question is about slots, not about props.

Answer (score 19):

If you have both named and unnamed slots with props:

Vue 3

```html
<template v-for="(_, name) in $slots" #[name]="slotData">
  <slot :name="name" v-bind="slotData || {}" />
</template>
```

Typescript version

```html
<template v-for="(_, name) in ($slots as {})" #[name]="slotData">
  <slot :name="name" v-bind="slotData || {}" />
</template>
```

Comment: If you use Prettier, and it keeps removing the parens on "($slots as {})", you can add this above that line: "<!-- prettier-ignore -->"

Answer (score 13):

I had EsLint errors because of the depreciated `:slot` and `$scopedSlots` attributes.

So I combined both of @Sumurai8 answers like this and it works great:

```
<template v-for="(_, slot) in $slots" v-slot:[slot]>
  <slot :name="slot"></slot>
</template>
```