# How to create a wrapper component in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I am trying to create a wrapper component around an existing component (`q-table` from the [quasar-framework](https://v1.quasar-framework.org/vue-components/table)).

```
<!-- MyTable.vue -->
<template>
    <q-table :title="title" ...>
        <template v-slot:top="props">
            ...
        </template>

        <template v-slot:body="props">
            <q-tr :props="props">
                ...
            </q-tr>
        </template>
    </q-table>
</template>
```

`<template v-slot:body="props">` and `<template v-slot:top="props">` are slots of the q-table component.

How to overwrite these slots in the App.vue:

```
<!-- App.vue -->
<template>
    <div>
        <my-table>
            ???
        </my-table>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuejs nested slots: how to pass slot to grandchild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430731/vuejs-nested-slots-how-to-pass-slot-to-grandchild)

Comment: @RaduDiță: Thanks for the hint. Thats a really similar issue!