# Vuejs - Create a parent component

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to create parent (wrapper) components in Vue? I've looked and I haven't been able to find anything

What I have in mind is the following (the v-something components are from the vuetify library):

```
//cardWrapper.js
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-card>
<template>

<script> 
  export default {
    blabla
  } 
</script>
```

then this should somehow be available so that I can in the main file

```
// index.vue
<template>
  <cardWrapper>
    <v-btn>Click Me!</v-btn>
  </cardWrapper>
</template>
```

I'm guessing this is a straightforward process and that I simply haven't been googling it correctly.
The only thing I've been able to find was to use dynamic components, but I would rather not pass components as properties

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430731/vuejs-nested-slots-how-to-pass-slot-to-grandchild

Comment: I think what you're describing is just a regular component with a slot. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: oh god I had already tried this but I accidentally always typed 'span' instead of 'slot'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:

custom component

```
//custom-parent.vue
<template>
  <custom-parent>
    <slot/>
  </custom-parent>
</template>
```

main file

```
//index.vue
<template>
  <custom-parent>
    <a>Hellohello</a>
  </custom-parent>
</template>
```