# Pass down activator slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

In Vue 1.x I used to do this:

Component1:

```
<template>
    <v-dialog>
        <slot name="activator" slot="activator"></slot>
    </v-dialog>
</template>
```

Component2:

```
<template>
    <component-1>
        <slot name="activator" slot="activator"></slot>
    </component-1>
</template>
```

So I could do this in Component3:

```
<template>
    <h3>I'm component 3</h3>

   <component-2>
       <template slot="activator">
           <v-btn></v-btn>
       </template>
    </component-2>
</template>
```

It worked fine. But how can I do the same using Vue's 2.6 `v-slot` syntax?

Replacing the "template" `slot`s in component 1 and 2 with this does not work:

```
<template v-slot:activator="{on}">
    <slot name="activator" v-on="on"></slot>
</template>
```

I can't find a way of proxying the "activator" slot from v-dialog all the way down to component 3.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, the solution is to re-bind the entire scope to the slot being "passed down", rather than just the `v-on` signal handler like this:

```
<template v-slot:activator="scope">
  <slot name="activator" v-bind="scope"></slot>
</template>
```

(detailed in this other answer)

[vue - how to pass down slots inside wrapper component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891858/vue-how-to-pass-down-slots-inside-wrapper-component)