# How to globally add styles to some components

Tags: vuetify.js

I would like to add some styles to some components for example v-chip I want to add some padding globally. I do not want to do it, or import a style file on each component that uses v-chip. I tried to add the styles to variables.scss it works fine but violate the caveats https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#caveats that produces duplicate css. Created a overwrites.scss file and add to it dose not work neither. Please if anyone know how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [caveats](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#caveats) CSS duplication is happened when you import any other stylesheet into variables.scss. As far as I understand, there is no any duplication happened when you haven't imported any CSS file. So, to configure variables in variables.scss is a good way to configure global styles.

If you need to configure styles which have no applicable variable (or you just prefer this way of styles configuration) you can:

a. Create your own component (e.g. XChip.vue) as a wrapper for v-chip.

```
<!-- XChip.vue -->
<template>
  <v-chip v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
    ...
  </v-chip>
</template>
```

b. Add necessary styles in this component

```
<style scoped>
  ...
</styles>
```

c. Then use it everywhere in your project when you need a chip.

You can find more information how to pass down slots here: [Vue - how to pass down slots inside wrapper component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891858/vue-how-to-pass-down-slots-inside-wrapper-component/52823029)